# Sending array to a certain class and retrieving two-dimensional array from it

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

Here is what I want to make, and error keeps occur. Hope someone can point out what's wrong with this.

1. Sending an array `raw`({1,2,3,4}) to `SelectNo` class.

   ```
   public class SelectTest {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

      int[] raw = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

      SelectNo select = new SelectNo(raw);
      select.select();

      }
   }
   ```
2. `SelectNo` class' `select()` function gives result, bunch of arrays including three numbers from `raw` without repetition. So the result has to be {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {2,3,4}. I know how to get the result printed out with the code below.

```
public class SelectNo {

    public int[] selected;
    public int[] raw;

    public SelectNo(int[] raw) {
        this.raw = raw; 
        this.selected = new int[3]; 
    }

    public void select() {
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.length - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < raw.length - 1; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < raw.length; k++) {
                    selected[0] = raw[i];
                    selected[1] = raw[j];
                    selected[2] = raw[k];
                    System.out.println(selected[0]+" "+selected[1]+" "+selected[2]);
                }
            }
        }

}
```

3. BUT the problem is, I want to save the bunch of arrays({1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {2,3,4}) as a two-dimensional array in `SelectTest`. So I changed the `select()` to return the two-dimensional array, 'addSelected'. I am not sure whether the `select()` is logical, since I get error.

```
public class SelectNo {

    public int[] selected;
    public int[] raw;
    public int no = 0; // added
    public int[][] addSelected; // added

    public SelectNo(int[] raw) {
        this.raw = raw;
        this.selected = new int[3];
        this.addSelected = new int[no][3]; //added
    }

    public int[][] select() { //changed to return int[][]
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.length - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < raw.length - 1; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < raw.length; k++) {
                    selected[0] = raw[i];
                    selected[1] = raw[j];
                    selected[2] = raw[k];
                    addSelected[no] = selected; //add array to 2 dimensional array
                    this.no = no + 1;
                }
            }
        } return addSelected; //return 2 dimensional array
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? Besides, `selected` is a reference to an array, and you are adding the same reference to `addSelected` over and over again, which probably will result having the same array in every row of your 2D array.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi This post was saved before I completed the sentence. Sorry for this. My question is, how can I add the different arrays(e.g. {1,2,3}, {1,2,4},{2,3,4}) to `addSelected`. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've said in the comment, the problem is that `selected` is a reference to an array, which means that it points to a segment of memory where the content of the array is stored. Basically you are doing a shallow copy instead of a deep copy of your array. To correct this you can do the following instead of `addSelected[no] = selected;`:

1. Use a `for` loop to insert every element from the `selected` array inside `addSelected[no]`.
2. Use [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-).

Comment: Thanks millions! Although I am trying to use two-dimensional arrays... :)